# Uncheck radio button

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to set up a simple Vue instance with a collection of radio buttons. The goal is that, if the user clicks on a radio button that is already checked, it will uncheck the respective radio button. But I couldn't do this using Vue yet. Here's my code so far:

HTML:

```
<div id="app">
    <div v-for="(val, key) in list">
        <input type="radio" name="radio" :value="val" v-model="selected" :id="val">
        <label :for="val" @click="uncheck( val )">{{ val }}</label>
    </div>
    <button @click="uncheckAll">Uncheck all</button>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data : {
            list: [ 'one', 'two', 'three' ],
            selected: 'two',
        },
        methods : {
            uncheck: function( val ){
                console.log( val, this.selected );
                if ( val == this.selected ){
                    this.selected = false;
                }
            },
            uncheckAll: function(){
                this.selected = false;
            }
        }
})
```

Seems like the `uncheck` method is called, but then the radio button triggers a `change` event and then updates the value of `selected` again. `uncheckAll` method works as expected, probably because it's not tied to the data using `v-model`.

Any tips or suggestions to make this work? Here's a pen I created for this example: https://codepen.io/diegoliv/pen/JrPBbG

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The difficulty is that `v-model` is changing the value of `selected` before you can examine it to see what its previous value is. You need another variable.

The idea is: when you click an item, it checks whether it matches `previouslySelected` (rather than `selected`). If it matches, unselect. Then set `previouslySelected` to the value of `selected`.

The `click` handler should be on the input, not on the label; it is the function of the label to forward clicks to the input, anyway.

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    list: ['one', 'two', 'three'],
    selected: 'two',
    previouslySelected: 'two'
  },
  methods: {
    uncheck: function(val) {
      if (val === this.previouslySelected) {
        this.selected = false;
      }
      this.previouslySelected = this.selected;
    },
    uncheckAll: function() {
      this.selected = false;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(val, key) in list">
    <input type="radio" name="radio" :value="val" v-model="selected" :id="val" @click="uncheck(val)">
    <label :for="val">{{ val }}</label>
  </div>
  <button @click="uncheckAll">Uncheck all</button>
</div>
```

**Note: the below method does not work with Vue 2.5 or later because clicking an already-selected radio does not cause a `set` to happen.** (thanks to Vlad T. in the comments)

A more in-the-data way of approaching it would be to have a computed based on your selected, and have its setter do the check for re-selecting. No click handler. Everything is handled in the normal course of setting the value.

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    list: ['one', 'two', 'three'],
    d_selected: 'two'
  },
  computed: {
    selected: {
      get() {
        return this.d_selected;
      },
      set(v) {
        if (v === this.d_selected) {
          this.d_selected = false;
        } else {
          this.d_selected = v;
        }
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    uncheckAll: function() {
      this.d_selected = false;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(val, key) in list">
    <input type="radio" name="radio" :value="val" v-model="selected" :id="val">
    <label :for="val">{{ val }}</label>
  </div>
  <button @click="uncheckAll">Uncheck all</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect! Both implementations works great. I went with your first suggestion for now, since my real implementation is a little bit more complex than the example I showed here, and using two variables and a helper method makes things easier for now. Thank you!

Comment: I tried the in-the-data way in jsfiddle and it looks that starting from Vue 2.5.0 clicking on radio input does not work. 'Uncheck all' button still works.

Answer (score 3):

Here goes a simple one without using `v-model` and just only takes one variable for storing the current selected value.

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    list: ['one', 'two', 'three'],
    selected: 'two'
  },
  methods: {
    uncheck: function (val) {
      if (val === this.selected) {
        this.selected = false
      } else {
        this.selected = val
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(val, key) in list">
    <input type="radio" :checked="selected===val" :id="val" @click="uncheck(val)" :key="'input' + key">
    <label :for="val" :key="'label' + key">{{ val }}</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`prevent` modifier](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers) to prevent the default behavior of clicking the label:

```
<label :for="val" @click.prevent="uncheck( val )">{{ val }}</label>
```

[Here's a working Codepen.](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PJYBRa)