# Uncheck radio button Angular 7 Bootstrap 4

Tags: angular, typescript, bootstrap-4, radio-button

I am using Angular 7 and Bootstrap 4. I am trying to have radio buttons that toggle but can be unchecked when clicked twice. Like shown [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46166448/9953550). Here is [my current implementation](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular5-bootstrap4-crud-device-list-simple-6xbtuc?file=app/app.component.html).

In my example you can see I can untoggle the button on clicking twice but I have a new problem. I would like to have an implementation that isolates the rows. In the sense that if you are answering a questionnaire you can pick a different answer in every row or leave the row blank.

My question is: how can I pick a different answer(button) in every row or leave the row blank? How can I uniquely identify a row in my code?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a working solution to my problem. This is it : [How to uncheck a radio button on its second click Angular 2+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55005641/how-to-uncheck-a-radio-button-on-its-second-click-angular-2).

This is a simple and scalable solution that works well.

Answer (score 0):

update:
Its a bit hard coded, but its a good start:
.ts:

```
  status: boolean = false;
  option=""
  option1=[false, false, false]
  option2=[false, false, false]
  option3=[false, false, false]

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2){}


  data = [{
    id:"1a",
    One:"Yes-1a",
    Two:"Maybe-1b",
    Three:"No-1c"
  },{
    id:"2a",
    One:"Yes-2a",
    Two:"Maybe-2b",
    Three:"No-2c"
  },
  {
    id:"3a",
    One:"Yes-3a",
    Two:"Maybe-3b",
    Three:"No-3c"
  }
  ]

  clickEvent1(i){
    this.option = 'option1 : ' + this.option1
    if(this.option1[i] == true){
      this.option1[i] = false
    }else{
      this.option1[i] = true
    }  
    this.option2[i] = false; this.option3[i] = false


}
  clickEvent2(i){

    this.option = 'option2 : ' + this.option2
    if(this.option2[i] == true){
        this.option2[i] = false
     } else{
        this.option2[i] =true
     }
      this.option1[i] = false; this.option3[i] = false
}
  clickEvent3(i){

    this.option = 'option3 : ' + this.option3
    if(this.option3[i] == true){
      this.option3[i] = false
    }else{
      this.option3[i] = true
    }
      this.option1[i] = false; this.option2[i] = false} 
}
```

.html:

```
<div class="card" style="height:400px">
  <div class="card-body no-gutters">

    <div *ngFor="let radio of data" class="btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
      <div class="row">
        <label class="btn btn-secondary col-4" 
        [ngClass]="option1 ? 'bbb' : ''">
          <input (click)="clickEvent1()" 
          type="radio" name="options" id="option1">
          {{radio.One}}
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-secondary col-4"
        [ngClass]="option2 ? 'bbb' : ''">
          <input (click)="clickEvent2()"
          type="radio" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off"> {{radio.Two}}
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-secondary col-4"
        [ngClass]="option3 ? 'bbb' : ''">
          <input (click)="clickEvent3()"
          type="radio" name="options" id="option3" autocomplete="off"> {{radio.Three}}
        </label>
        {{option}}
      </div>
    </div>


  </div>
</div>
```

//sorry I dont know how to save the changes on stackblitz :(

Comment: Thank you but this doesn’t answer my question. I have updated the question to make it more clear...

Comment: you can use index in the for loop like this:
<div *ngFor="let radio of data; index as i" class="btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
later if I have some time I'll update my answer

Comment: Thanks but I found a better scalable solution. I really appreciate you help though. Thank you.