# How to uncheck a radio button on its second click Angular 2+

Tags: angular, typescript, bootstrap-4, radio-button

I am trying to implement Radio button uncheck on second click in Angular 2+ [as done here in angularjs](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bootstrap4-dvsfe3?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts). I have an array of objects that get displayed using *ngFor, therefore I have multiple radio button groups in one form. I need an implementation that will onlt uncheck the said radio button/ All the implementations I have tried keep checking and unchecking multiple buttons while other implementations don't work at all.

[This is my current code right now.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bootstrap4-lmaetv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) How can I implement Radio button uncheck on second click using typescript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to bind the radio value to an `ngModel` and either listen to the `ngModelChange` or `click` event instead of `change`.

This answer might help you as well https://stackoverflow.com/a/42447116/4544288

Comment: Could you please please integrate that answer with [the code I provided](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bootstrap4-dvsfe3?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html). Please, that way I'll be able to understand it better.Thank you.

Comment: Your model doesn't make any sense to me, so I cleaned up the code to provide the functionality you asked https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bootstrap4-jo5acq.

This is a solution with `[checked]` binding, same can be achieved using `[(ngModel)]`

Comment: Thank you but I am looking for a way to deselect a radio button that is in a button group and the button group is repeated using *ngFor... I have updated my code in the question to make more sense... The radio buttons are in the context of a questionnaire... so I want the user to be able to click on the radio button to select then click again to deselect if they want to leave the question blank.

Comment: The issue with the current answer is that it is not scale-able with a lot of radio buttons...

Comment: You have really helped me thank you very much.. I've spent so much time on it,. This is exactly what I've been looking for!

Comment: I have just gone through the solution you provided and understood the code.. had to come back and say I am really really impressed by it's simplicity...I think I spent to much time trying to make it work that I thought the solution would be complex... cheers.

Comment: @YulePale I'm struggling with this, can you show me your implementation, please?

Comment: @roymckrank sorry, I can’t find my old code and can’t remember what I did. Maybe Try asking a new question

Answer (score 0):

Please try your code with more radio buttons. Is it works well, you able to try to un-select the selected radio button when you click it again?
I means your stackblitz code:
stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bootstrap4-jo5acq.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use ngModel then you can use following approach

```js
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
    <label>
        <input
            #radioInput
            type="radio"
            [value]="item.id"
            [checked]="item.checked"
            (input)="onChange(item, radioInput)"
        />
        <span>{{ item.label ? item.label : item.labelKey }}</span>
    </label>
</div>
```

and in .ts file

```js
onChange(chosenItem: FieldRadioItem, inpCheckbox: HTMLInputElement) {

    inpCheckbox.checked = !inpCheckbox.checked;
    ...
}
```

Class `FieldRadioItem` contains only fields `id`, `label` and `checked`.
Tested on Angular 11