# Uncheckeck a individual radio button from loop of radio buttons in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a query from the database that brings me several data, each one with its respective radio button that when clicking on them opens a modal window and passes certain data to be updated, in this modal window I have a cancel button, I would like to give it cancel the radio buttom that I previously marked will be unmarked

```
<tr v-for="(flt, f) in filterResponse" :key="f">
  <td v-if="flt.state === 1>                                              
    <input 
       type="radio" 
       @change="dlgComments = !dlgComments; updateType(flt.user_payment_id, flt.payment_amount)" 
       :name="`filter${f}`"
    >       
  <td>
</tr>
```

Button in modal window

```
<v-btn id="button-save" color="error darken-1" :disabled="!valid" text @click="uncheck(); dlgComments = false">Cancelar</v-btn>
```

I need to implement the uncheck() function but I don't know how to catch the specific radio button that I press and set the checked state to false?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46166125/uncheck-radio-button

Answer (score 0):

I managed to capture the id of the radio through the attribute with querySelector from a method

```
const confirmed = document.querySelector(`#rbConfirmed${this.radioId}`);
confirmed.checked = false;
```